# Creating a word document from html and chart control using C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, pie-chart

Currently I am having a aspx page with a table and and multiple ASP.Net chart control(pie chart). I need to generate a Microsoft Word Document with all the content that are present in the aspx page(might be in a button click or in the page load) and the format should be same as on the page. Please suggest a approach how to proceed.

I have found some articles to generate with normal html but it doesn't render the charts to the word doc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use DevExpress reports components they have very good solution for Export in different formats you can look at this demo:
http://mvc.devexpress.com/Report/PivotGridAndChartReport